# MongoDB Atlas Data API findOne wrapping JSON in document object?

Tags: json, rest, mongodb-atlas

POSTing to MongoDB's Data API REST endpoint for findOne with the following body:

```
{
  "collection": "MyCollection",
  "database": "MyDatabase",
  "dataSource": "MyCluster",
    "filter": {
        "_id": { "$oid": "MyObjectId" }
    },
    "projection": {
        "_id": 0,
        "GoLive": 1
    }
}
```

returns:

```
{
  "document": {
    "GoLive": "My GoLive Date Here"
  }
}
```

but according to there own documentation:

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/api/data-api/#choose-a-response-data-format

it should just return the record, as such:

```
{
  "GoLive": "My GoLive Date Here"
}
```

Can anyone explain why? which is correct?

Seems like if I want to deserialize this into a C# object, I will currently need to load it into a JObject first and extract the inner document object for deserialization.